# Parentheses Reduction

Tags: java

I have written the following:

```
if ( ( ( weight < 160 && ( age <= 27 && age >= 22 ) )
    && ( ( height < 72 ) && ( ( !isASmoker ) && ( isMale ) ) )
    && ( ( isGoodLooking ) && ( isAbleToRelocate) ) ) ) {
```

Can I reduce the parentheses?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you sure can.  Have you tried?

Comment: You only use `&&`, so yes. Basically, you can drop all except the outer parenthesis. But you should not desing `if` clauses like this. This leads to unmaintainable code.

Comment: Why do you have all those parentheses in the first place? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+operator+precedence

Comment: Why don't you create a couple methods and call them from the if-statement? That would make it more maintainable and easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly stated in [Turing85's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349854/parentheses-reduction#comment50682845_31349854), you can actually remove every parenthesis except the outer ones

```
if  (weight < 160 && age <= 27 && age >= 22 
        && height < 72 &&   !isASmoker  &&  isMale   
        &&   isGoodLooking  &&  isAbleToRelocate  )
```

this is the minimum number of parethesis you can use. The maximum number is... well, virtually infinite (finite number, obviously, but infinite possibilities). You can add as many as you like, as long as it is sintactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you correctly understood java operators precedence then this can be reduced to minimum parentheses :

```
if ( ( weight < 160 && ( age <= 27 && age >= 22 ) )
&& (  height < 72  &&  !isASmoker  &&  isMale )
&& (  isGoodLooking  &&  isAbleToRelocate ) ) {
```

For more refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Edit :- Actually if you consider if condition with 'and' operator checks for the next condition ony if first is true, this can be logically further reduced to

```
if ( weight < 160 &&  age <= 27 && age >= 22 
&&  height < 72  &&  !isASmoker  &&  isMale 
&&  isGoodLooking  &&  isAbleToRelocate ) {
```

Comment: If think it could be reduced even more since it is just AND. Only the outer parenthesis should matter no ?

Comment: You wouldn't need any of the inner parenthesis

Comment: Thanks, turns out it works even with no parenthesis except for one

Comment: Now it's better ! @austinwernli this statement was not you but I often get down votes without explanations at all on either questions or answer which is sometimes driving me crazy

Comment: @LonniBesançon i just miss that point...thanks by the way for the deleted comment ;)